# Copy and rename files matching a pattern

Tags: puppet

I have this bash script that I would like to translate into puppet:

```
for f in $PROJECT_DIR/config/*.example
do
  cp -n "$f" "${f%\.example}"
done
```

Essentially, find all files matching a certain pattern (`*.example`), copy those files to a directory, and rename (omit the `.example`)

Any way to accomplish this with puppet in a way the ensures each of the files are actually created?

Comment: I'm sure this can be done, but it's almost certainly _not the right thing to do_. Can you explain what the full context is?

Comment: I had a feeling I'd get told something like this. Setting up an application vm. `.example` files are filled with dev valid params, replaced in a different way on prod. This manifest is dev specific.

Comment: @clang1234 Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @utrecht I did but waaay over complicated things in the process. I'll post my solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this with a ruby script that gets ran by puppet. It's all gross. Don't do this.
https://gist.github.com/caseylang/b57eee59f3d7f1fd429c